# Does Dropbox API V2 Still Support Sandbox?

Tags: dropbox-api

I'm working for an app that needs to transition to V2 support.

In V1 there was a sandbox option, where Dropbox would create a directory for the app under the apps/ folder.

I'm not seeing this option in V2, though I could just be mistaken. But while before, many of the requests supported a “root” parameter, that no longer seems to be an option.

So has this been disabled or is there simply a different way of going about it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, Dropbox API v2 still supports the sandbox, a.k.a. the "app folder" permission. The permissions are documented [here in the developer guide](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/reference/developer-guide#app-permissions).

Dropbox API v2 no longer uses the "root" parameter, where you would explicitly specify `sandbox`. API v2 automatically detects this from your app registration.